Input to machine learning model
I trained a bert based model that I had been working on for quite sometime now. After the training, I got a few files in the model directory - pytorch_model.bin, training_args.bin, merges.txt, vocab.json. Now I want to test the model by providing an input to the model and examine it's output. But i'm unable to understand how am i supposed to do so.
I tried looking on the internet and was suggested to use Gradio.

If you simply wish to utilize a pre-trained PyTorch model, please follow the instructions provided below.
import torch

# Load the model
model = torch.load('model.bin')
input_data = torch.tensor([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])  # Example input data

with torch.no_grad():
    output = model(input_data)
print(output)

